# Switching regulator output is unstable

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck

I have a problem in buck regulator. I'm using [L4970A](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00000080.pdf) to make a buck regulator with a variable output that can be adjusted using a potentiometer.

Output is becoming a ramp when I set the output voltage to be above 7 V; it goes up directly and slowly goes down to 7.5 V, and repeated again.

I'm using an inductor that is larger than it should be, my calculation is about 50 to 150 uH, but I use 11 mH. Is that the problem?

This is my design, the same I saw from [this](http://www.21icsearch.com/download.shtml?id=6B07BFFD5E10AE0E) application note, pg.38

This is output voltage below 7 V
[image]

This is output voltage above 7 V
[image]

Could you know what my problem is???
Thanks a lot!!!

**Edit 1**

I've changed the inductor value to 200 uH, and I tried it to supply laptop with supply input 24 V. It charged the laptop when the laptop was turned on, although the voltage is not stable when I saw it in oscilloscope, but when I turned it off, it won't charge...

Anybody could tell me why it was happen???

Comment: You can post the image on a free server and post the link to it here. We'll add it to your question.

Comment: 11mH is way too high for an SMPS. An inductor this big may put the converter in [discontinuous mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter#Discontinuous_mode).

Comment: @abdullahkahraman There's nothing inherently wrong with DCM, and a big inductor means lower di/dt and a tendency to go into CCM, not DCM.

Comment: We'll believe you if you say the input is 24 V, there's no need to post a 2 megapixel photo for that.

Comment: I haven't resized it yet, haha.... -_-v

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The large inductor value does have some design implications:

1. It's going to make the converter tend to operate in continuous conduction mode, which has loop stability ramifications (you generally need a type-3 compensator with low gain)
2. It's going to affect the transient response of the converter by limiting the current slew rate.
3. Is this inductor intended to carry DC current? Such high values are common for EMI inductors, not output chokes.

If you're experimenting with a reference design, it's always recommended to start with the exact BOM that the manufacturer suggests - at least you get some assurance that the circuit will work to some degree.

**Edit #1**

Your input is 24V, and when you try and adjust the output higher than 7V, the controller loses regulation. The output is essentially rising up to a voltage just below the input, most likely only limited by the maximum duty cycle supported by the part. This could be for several reasons.

Your voltage feedback should be via a resistor divider from the output to ground, with the midpoint going to pin 11. The converter will regulate the output so that pin 11 is at 5.1V.

Is your clock stable? You should be able to see a clean ramp on the timing capacitor (no jitter).

Is your reference stable? The 5.1V on pin 14 should be rock-solid.

What compensation components do you have from pin 10 to ground? I would suggest removing what's there and replacing it with a fairly large capacitor (1uF ceramic), and try your experiment again. The impedance from pin 10 to ground is your loop compensation, which determines the overall stability of the converter (along with operating frequency, output RC filter and load). Since you have a radically different inductor, you'll probably need to change the compensation for stability.

Comment: I use different value of inductor because I can't find the exact or similar amount... But now I wanna make one...

Comment: @Wardhana There are tons of off-the-shelf inductors for small DC power supplies available on the market. If you really want to make one, the easiest way is to buy a toroidal core and wind turns onto it. The core will usually have an inductance factor associated with it (nH per turn squared) allowing you to set your inductance as you see fit.

Comment: Not in my city, unfortunately...
How can I know that inductance factor? Is there any list of it?

Comment: @Wardhana It will be specified on the datasheet. Take a look at [these Kool-Mu](http://www.mag-inc.com/products/powder-cores/kool-mu) toroids - the inductance factor is listed as AL in the table.

Comment: what do you think about the picture I gave above? Do you think the problem is because of the inductor??? 
Or any other reason??

Comment: I've read your edited answer. Thanks, I'll check it.

But in the design (application note page 38), pin 14 is not conected. So, is it really important to check it, or actually it should be connected somewhere?

If voltage in feedback input when the potensiometer valued 0 is not 5.1 V, what could be the reason??

Do you think this design can be use to regulate power from solar cell (about 120 W) to supply, let say, notebook??

Thanks a lot again!! Really appreciate your help   *ps: I've changed my inductor to 200 uH, doesn't change the output so much...

Comment: I've asked another question above. Hope you don't mind to answer it. THANKS!!! ^^

Comment: @Wardhana Usually an external capacitor is needed on the reference coming out of the IC to keep it stable. If the feedback pin is below 5.1V, some other protection mechanism in the IC is constraining the duty cycle. You'll need to figure out which one it is :)

Comment: I've changed the inductor value to 200 uH, and I tried it to supply laptop with supply input 24 V. It charged the laptop when the laptop was turned on, although the voltage is not stable when I saw it in oscilloscope, but when I turned it off, it won't charge...

could you tell me why it was happen???

^^

Comment: @Wardhana Most laptops communicate with the charger using a specific protocol, so I'm surprised it was able to charge at all.