# Buck Regulator Output is too Small

Tags: solar-cell, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter

I'm making a buck regulator using L4970A using circuit from [this](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/APPLICATION_NOTE/CD00003796.pdf) application note figure 60 , except for the inductor. I change i to 180 uH

I wanna make it to be a power adaptor for laptop with solar cell source (about 100 W, Voc 27 V, Isc 5A), and the regulator itself can hold current to 10 A max, said the datasheet

As you know, usually laptop needs current from about 1.5 A-4 A, depends on it's using battery or not and how the laptop works. I've succeeded to make my regulator give supply to the laptop, but the current is too small to make it becoming primary supply.

Does anyone know what's wrong with the design? What actually limits the current of buck regulator??

I test this circuit using Asus A43SJ

For Russel, this is my inductor

[image: Inductor I use]

I don't know either the wire type or the core type exactly, but because it's not magnetic, I think it's iron powder. Outer diameter 2.3 cm and inner diameter 1.2 cm

Comment: Slowest link ever? 6.1 KB/sec. I'll be back after my cup of tea.

Comment: This is related to your [previous question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34185/switching-regulator-output-is-unstable), where in the comments I stated that most laptops use a specific protocol to enable charging. Remove the laptop from the equation and test your power supply with resistors before concluding that 'the buck doesn't work'.

Comment: @Madmanguruman Yap, you're right...
Okay, I'll try and tell the results...

Comment: @Madmanguruman it is the SMBus protocol, right?

Comment: Side note, please try not to sign your posts with a thank you line.

Comment: @abdullahkahraman Some Dell products use a 1-wire EEPROM protocol, so I don't think it's SMBus per se.

Comment: You need to provide MUCH MORE information. Page 42 has 3 circuits and they are very sketchy. There are many pins that can affect operation. You need to show a circuit wit all connections on it. Page 40 figure 53 seems to be close to what you need. What Vout have you set? What design operating frequency. What current will your inductor support without saturating? How do you know? Inductor MUST be suitable. IC Current limit MUST be hogh enough if used.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Someone changed my link to the pdf... It's different from I refer to before... But I've edited the question. I mean circuit in figure 60.
I set output in 19 V. Frequency about 227 kHz. I made my inductor myself, but I'm not sure about it's characteristic.

Comment: @Madmanguruman I test my circuit using asus laptop. I don't think it has protocol or something like that in it's adaptor. CMIIW

Comment: @abdullahkahraman What is SMBUS protocol?

Comment: As far as I know, it is a protocol that is used by motherboard to communicate with the laptop battery, for example. More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Bus).

Comment: @Wardhana You said the inducance is 180 uH. How do you know? Did you measure it? If so, what did you use to measure with? Or if calculated, what core parameters did you use? That's about 16 turns or Al = 180 uH / (16^2) =~ 700 NH/turn^2. Knowing the core material is important BUT the measurements that I suggested will show how well it works with a resistive load.

Comment: @Wardhana Based on what? Here's a link where [an Asus charger is described as having an EPROM in it](http://acadapter.oggix.org/tag/asus-eee-pc-1000h-ac-adapter/)...

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I measure it with LCR meter, [boonton 5110](https://www.valuetronics.com/detail/Used-boonton-5110.cfm#.T-5U1tUUMpY), with 1kHz Frequency.

So, it really could be that the limiter of the current is the inductor characteristic???

Comment: @Madmanguruman Just my opinion, haha -_-v
because I don't think universal charger will have that kind of protocol either, but it could charge (again, it's my opinion)
I'll check it again.

Answer (score 1):

[L4970A data sheet here](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00000080.pdf)

[Your cited application note here](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/APPLICATION_NOTE/CD00003796.pdf) - veryy extensive and useful.

Fig 60 circuit that you say you used is shown below.
 The circuit looks potentially OK as is.

> Frequency about 227 kHz.
>    I made my inductor myself, but I'm not sure about it's characteristic.

The ability of the inductor to carry the current required without saturating is 
crucial. Can you provide a picture of the inductor and describe the core material used. At a minimum if a picture is not available please provide construction details with core material and dimensions.

What voltage does the laptop require.
 If 19V then at 1A it looks like R = V/I = 19/1 ~= 20 Ohms load and at 4A it looks like ~= 5 ohms.
 At say 10 Ohms you'd get ~= 2A.
 Power = V x I ~= 40W

When you load it with a 10 Ohm, 40W rated resistor, what happens?
 Use an app[ropriate length of Nichrome wire (eg from an old heater or toaster element)or say 4 x 10W, 10Ohm resistors in series parallel (2S2P).

[image]

Comment: Would the user who UP voted this post just now (1st upvote)(about 1110 UTC June 29th) please let me know who they are. I of course have no problem with the upvote. It happens to be a "special vote" for reasons that are essentially irrelevant but it would be fun/nice to know who the voter was. As upvoters often enough identify themselves this will hopefully not be a problem. RM

Comment: It's me who upvote it, haha... *sorry if it's wrong, I'm a newbie...

Comment: I've uploaded the picture above.

Comment: @Wardhana - no problem with the upvote :-). It increased my user reputation to 40,003 FWIW. (Possibly very little indeed :-) )

Comment: I've tested it with power supply 24 V and variable resistor 40 ohm, set to 10 ohm. When I set the output to 19 V, The current output is good, it's about 1.80 A. So, is the unmatched current in my test before because I use laptop as my load?

Comment: @Wardhana - If it works with a resistive load and fails with a laptop load AND another "correct" charger provides more current with a laptop load then "Occams Razor" suggests there is something different between your charger and your supply. You may be able to "get inside" a chaarger and apply your supply where it gets its internal 19V from so its interface electronic still apply. If that works you have proved the point (probably :-) ).

Comment: So, you mean I have to cut the 19V supply in an adapter and change it with my supply???

Comment: @Wardhana - I mean that IF your buck regulator works perfectly with a resistive load but not with a laptop THEN using your supply as the energy source for a known working laptop adaptor will allow the adaptor to provide any "protocols" and handshaking. If this works it shows you where the problem is. The voltage may be 19v and may be some other voltage depending on the laptop power supply design.